# using icons of more than 1 stylesheets causing height/ alignment problem

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to use different icons from different stylesheets as not all the icons are available in 1 stylesheet that I wanted to use. When I tryto do that it causes the height problem.One icon leaves in upside and leaves some bottom space and another icon looks as it is required to be. What can be done to align them with same height? if you see the height of last icon of font awesome left some bottom space...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
.footer a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width:20%;
  bottom:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.footer a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.footer a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

</style>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you footer to display as flex could solve the issue:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
        .footer {
          display: flex;
           position: fixed;
           left: 0;
           bottom: 0;
           width: 100%;
           background-color: red;
           color: white;
           text-align: center;
        }
        .footer a {
          /* float: left; */
          display: flex; /* Consider flex layout */
          color: black;
        justify-content: center; /* Alignment of icons */
          padding: 14px 0px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 17px;
          width:20%;
          bottom:0;
          margin-bottom:0;
        }

        .footer a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }

        .footer a.active {
          background-color: #2196F3;
          color: white;
        }

        </style>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>

        <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
        <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

        <div class="footer">
          <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
              <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i></a>
        </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: + .footer > a:nth-child(4){display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center}

Comment: @VXp thanks, i have added justify-content to the .footer a

Comment: The point is to vertically align the 4th icon, cuz atm. it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

try this, added line-height and font-size to 'i' tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
.footer a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*removed padding*/
  width:20%;
  bottom:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  
}

.footer a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.footer a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}
/* added this */
.footer a i{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

</style>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```